# AJAX not returning any response in console log

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am working on a group project and am trying to get my API to return a response in the console log. I worked out any errors, but I am getting no response at all when I click submit.

JavaScript

```
var zipcode = "";

function localMovieSearch() { 
    var queryURL = "http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/movies/showings?startDate=" + "2017-01-01" + "&zip=" + "75206" + "&api_key=guyv9by6h494tz4s9xfvpqrq";



    $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET"
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
};


$("#movieZipSearch").on("click", function(event){
    localMovieSearch();
    zipcode = $("#movieZipInput").val().trim();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l6 xl6">
        <div class="panel-boxes">
           <div class="panel-heading">SEARCH FOR LOCAL MOVIES NOW PLAYING</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="movieZipInput">
                        <button type="search" class="btn" id="movieZipSearch" style="margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 15px">Search</button>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="panel-body recipesContainer" id="movieZipOutput" ></div>    
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If there is a form involved...prevent default on form submit or change button type to *"button"*. Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Not much troubleshooting info given. Also make sure button exists at the time your code runs

Comment: Thank you. I often forget to prevent default until I am over an hour into troubleshooting.

Comment: Page reloading should have been a good clue

Comment: Actually the page wasn't refreshing on click. It's still not returning any response either.

Comment: So does event get triggered? is request made in dev tools network?

Comment: The request is being made and returning OK

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Gg9mj - screenshot of dev tools network

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t7whee6d/  If you try to look at the response in the network tab of your browser, you should see that it is complaining about a parse error.  As you have the content type set on the response as application/json, jQuery will try to auto parse it for you, but if it is invalid will error.  I would suggest reviewing your response and making sure it is valid json.  In the mean time you should be able to put `dataType: 'text'` on your ajax to make it not try to auto parse it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a go when I get back to my computer.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/t7whee6d/1/  Updated it with the `dataType: 'text'`.  The console log shows that there is no data being returned, and no data is also considered invalid json.

Comment: I am getting no data returned as well. I apologize. I am still learning APIs and AJAX. It's taking me a while to wrap my head around how to troubleshoot the calls.

Comment: A good way to troubleshoot API calls is to get yourself a good REST client.  You can search the chrome/firefox app stores for them, most are free.  They allow you to easily try your api calls independently from javascript, so if they don't work there, you know it's an issue with the endpoint, and not the javascript.  After you get that working, then all you have left is getting javascript to call it the same way and, ignoring potential CORS issues that javascript would encounter that the REST client would not see, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. Doing that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation page](http://developer.tmsapi.com/io-docs) and the [sample code](http://developer.tmsapi.com/Sample_Code) the API `/movies/showings` accepts request as (I have changed the `startDate` parameter only with value today):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var zipcode = "";
    function localMovieSearch() { 
        var queryURL = "http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/movies/showings?startDate=" + "2018-01-02" + "&zip=" + "75206" + "&api_key=guyv9by6h494tz4s9xfvpqrq";

        $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).fail(function(){
            console.log("error")
        });
    };
    $("#movieZipSearch").on("click", function(event){
        localMovieSearch();
        zipcode = $("#movieZipInput").val().trim();
    });
</script>
```

Your code looks OK. Just make sure to test the API request first at http://developer.tmsapi.com/io-docs . So, that you will be assured of the response. Your console is not printing anything because for `startDate` parameter you sent may not have appropriate data at server, because in this case too server is sending the status code `200 OK`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Holy cow. I can't believe I forgot to change the year. I see 2018 being long already.

Comment: You are welcome!! It is better to go to documemt generally. They are our first guide to do something new. :)